# Inputting data into an object

Tags: java, object, getter-setter

I'm doing a homework assignment, where we were asked to create a banking system. The first option is to create a customer and to store their information in a customer object. The start of my `create_customer()` method asks for their name and stores it into a newly create `Customer` object, but when i call the `getName()` method, nothing comes back. Here's the initial class `Atm` which holds all the actions for each option.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Atm
 {
   private ArrayList<Customer> cust;
  private int starting_account_number;
  private int starting_customer_number;
  private String admin_pin;
  private int interest_rate;
  private int transaction_counter;
  ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader(System.in);

  public Atm()  // constructor
  {
    cust = new ArrayList<>(100);
    starting_account_number = 1001;
    starting_customer_number = 101;
    admin_pin = "abcd";
    interest_rate = 5;
    transaction_counter = 0;
  }

void create_customer()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    System.out.println("Please input your name: ");
    customer.setName(console.readLine());
    customer.getName();
    while (customer.istrue)
        {
        System.out.println("Please input a 4 digit alphanumeric PIN: ");
        customer.setPin(console.readLine());
        if (customer.istrue == false) break;
        }
    System.out.println("A system generated ID was created for you, it is: ");
    String customer_id = String.valueOf(starting_customer_number);
    customer.setId(customer_id); // set customer ID
    starting_customer_number++; //incrememnt customer ID
    System.out.print(customer.getId());
    cust.add(customer); //puts the customer object into atm class arraylist
}
```

Here's the customer class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer
{
 public boolean istrue;
 private String name;
 private String id; // 3 digits string
 private String pin;    // 4 digits string
 private ArrayList<Account> acct;
 private double total_bal;  // for all accounts



 public Customer()  //constructor
 { 
     acct = new ArrayList<>(100);
     istrue = true;
     name = "NoName";
     id = "000";
     pin = "0000";
     total_bal = 0;

 }
//  public cal_total_bal()  { }

  public String getName() {
       return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public String getId() {
      return id;
  } 

  public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getPin() {
      return pin;
  }

  public void setPin(String pin) {
      this.pin = pin;
    if (pin.length() != 4)
    {
        System.out.println("That was not 4 digits, please input a 4 digit alphanumeric PIN: ");
}
else istrue = false;

  }
```

Comment: It seems your not printing `customer.getName()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, forgot to print out the method! silly me haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method

```
customer.getName();
```

But you are not actually doing anything with it..  you might want to print it:

```
System.out.println(customer.getName());
```